# How to convert this COUNTIFS into Power Query for better performance purpose?

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery, countif

I'm using this in a table on Excel, but it takes too long to calculate every time - no doubt.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(T:T;T9371;R:R;">="&EOMONTH('Sheet1'!$B$2;-1)+1;R:R;"<="&EOMONTH('Sheet1'!$B$3;0))>0;1;0)`

The idea is to find occurrences of that customer in the current month and mark it as 1, if there's any and 0 if not. Also find the ones who have bought in the last month...

How would we have it set in Power Query, instead?

Here's a sample of the data:

| CustomerID | Customer | Date | Item | ThisMonth | LastMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T45678 | ABC | 09/15/21 | Product A | 1 | 0 |
| T45678 | ABC | 09/15/21 | Product B | 1 | 0 |
| T123645 | BGT | 08/10/21 | Product A | 0 | 1 |

Thank you!

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide a sample of data **as text** which can be copy/pasted into an excel worksheet; and also a screenshot of the expected results from that data.  *(You might also check to see if your performance improves by not using whole column references -- create a Table and use structured references instead)*

Comment: Is it necessary to look at all 1,048,576 rows?  You could speed up the formula considerably by just looking at the relevant range.

Comment: Don't replicate the formula in PQ:  Add custom column with first of month date (BOM). Then group by name/BOM and aggregate with Count.  Add custom column with formula: `=if Count>0 then 1 else 0`.  Then expand the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how I would do this in PQ.

Please read the comments in the code and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"CustomerID", type text}, {"Customer", type text}, {
            "Date", type date}, {"Item", type text}}),

    //Normalize all dates to start of month for grouping
    //date type => datetime so can be used in grouping aggregation below
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "BOM", 
        each Date.StartOfMonth([Date]), type datetime),

    //group by Customer and BOM
    //  then return 1 or 0 if in current or previous month
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"CustomerID", "BOM"}, {
         {"all", each _, type table 
            [CustomerID=nullable text, 
            Customer=nullable text, 
            Date=nullable date, 
            Item=nullable text,
            BOM=date]},
        {"This Month", each if Date.IsInCurrentMonth([BOM]{0}) then 1 else 0, Int64.Type}, 
        {"Last Month", each if Date.IsInPreviousMonth([BOM]{0}) then 1 else 0, Int64.Type}
        }),
        
    //Expand the table to restore ungrouped listings
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all", 
        {"Customer", "Date", "Item"}, {"Customer", "Date", "Item"}),

    //Don't need BOM column anymore
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded all",{"BOM"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

**Original Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]